# Roboelectric : How to resolve depended object

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have one activity and I am testing one method of it using Roboelectic Framework but I am getting null pointer exception.

following is test code

```
@Test
public void processTest() throws Exception {
 MyActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MyActivity.class);

activity.setValue();
tView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.text);
assertEquals(“1”,tView.getText().toString());
}
```

following is setValue method of activity

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tView;
```

@Inject Student s;

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    tView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.text);
}

public void setValue() {
    String id = s.getId();
    tView.setText(S);
}
```

I am getting null pointer error on `String id = s.getId();` line when I run test

I know `s` is null. but my question how to make it available in Test using Roboelectric without using Mokito ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you pasted your code exactly as it run? onCreate should have parameter of Bundle, and the activity has not called setConentView before you do findViewById, and some other problems....

In general, The activity constructed by Robolectric.setupActivity should be ready for use in the rest of the test case, and onCreate(Bundle) should have been executed before return.

Comment: This is just sample code not real. main concern is that object is not getting initialise in oncreate or in that method. that is getting initialise somewhere else. Please see my edits. I just want to initialise with some fake date before tasing as I am testing that method individually.

Comment: @MKY I tried to build such a test. It work for me. (with Robolectric 3.8)

https://gist.github.com/hkhc/b787cf607e177d54253e36c6eb15ba54

Comment: Suppose student is interface and I have somewhere implemented in someother class and I have injected student and I want to manupulate that and test. Is there any way?